# How is Prometheus connected to Alien vs. Predator in the chronological sense?

Tags: plot-explanation, prometheus, alien, chronology, aliens-vs-predator

At the end of [Prometheus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_%28film%29), we saw that a creature was born from the body of the dead engineer, which was essentially identical to the Alien creature pictured in the Alien vs. Predator movies (a [Xenomorph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_%28creature_in_Alien_franchise%29)).

Now my question is how are they connected chronologically? I imagine that the [AVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVP:_Alien_vs._Predator) happens in the present time but Prometheus is dated in the future.

Comment: This topic is similar to the one here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21182/how-does-the-xenomorph-evolution-timeline-work-in-the-alien-predator-universe

Comment: Simply put? Not!

Comment: I see this possibility.
1. Prometheus
2. AVP
3. Alien
4. Aliens
Etc. I would like to see a relationship between the engineers and predators. Enemies for sure.
Would predate our creation. And could allow both franchises to occupy the same universe.
Opening other spin off options for the time before/between/after these movies. I like the possibilities this could present.

Comment: It's a shame they are not connected as bringing Predator into the story of the Engineer's would have made things really interesting. But I think the timeline is affected as Prometheus is set in the future & AVP is in the present. One thing that was cool though was the fact that the Engineer's mask resembled the Predator's helmet! Anyway, whatever direction the next story takes, I'm sure it will be pretty cool!

Comment: Oh dear god. Please tell me the alien from *Alien* isn't now thought of as "the Alien creature pictured in the Alien vs. Predator movies".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the [***Prometheus* IMDb FAQ**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1446714/faq#.2.1.41):

> **It should be noted that AvP franchise is not considered part of the official canon of the *Alien* saga** [...]
>
> *Prometheus* is considered by both Ridley Scott and the film's producers to be the first film in the *Alien* series.

From an [**interview with Damon Lindelof**](http://www.craveonline.com/film/interviews/190017-fundamental-mysteries-damon-lindelof-on-prometheus-and-star-trek-2):

> [...] Look, as to what’s canon and what’s not canon, for me as a screenwriter it’s transcended by Ridley as a director.
>
> Here’s the thing. Ridley invented this. He created this *Alien* universe. He birthed it out of his own heart and soul. So he gets to do whatever it is he wants to do and **he wanted to use Weyland as a conduit in the story, and was not interested at all when I said to him, *“You know, Weyland was a character in one of the Alien Vs. Predator movies,”*** he just sort of looked at me like I had just slapped him in the face. That was the beginning, middle and end of all *Alien Vs. Predator* references in our story process.

Answer (score 17):

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_series) says -

> Prometheus was originally intended as a direct prequel to the 1979 science
>   fiction horror film Alien, set approximately 30 years before the
>   events depicted in the film. While the finished film explored a more
>   stand-alone mythology based upon the race of giant beings discovered
>   by the crew of the Nostromo in Alien, it is, as acknowledged in the
>   end credits, based on elements from the original film.

As stated in [Alien vs. Predator Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_vs._Predator_%28film%29)

> In a 2002 interview, Scott's concept for a story was "to go back to
>   where the alien creatures were first found and explain how they were
>   created"; this project eventually became Scott's 2012 film Prometheus.
>   On learning that Fox intended to pursue Alien vs. Predator, Cameron
>   believed the film would "kill the validity of the franchise" and
>   ceased work on his story, "To me, that was Frankenstein Meets
>   Werewolf. It was Universal just taking their assets and starting to
>   play them off against each other...Milking it."[38] After viewing
>   Alien vs. Predator, however, Cameron remarked that "it was actually pretty good. I
>   think of the five Alien films, I'd rate it third. I actually liked it.
>   I actually liked it a lot."[38] Conversely, Ridley Scott had no
>   interest in the Alien vs. Predator films. When asked in May 2012 if he
>   had watched them, Scott laughed, "No. I couldn't do that. I couldn't
>   quite take that step.

It's clear that Ridley Scott never in a favor of `Alien vs. Predator Franchise` and that's the reason that his film `Prometheus` only connected to Alien Franchise, it doesn't have any connection to  `Alien vs. Predator` films.

As stated in [Prometheus Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_%28film%29)

> Development of the film began in the early 2000s as a fifth
>   installment in the Alien franchise. Scott and director James Cameron
>   developed ideas for a film that would serve as a prequel to Scott's
>   1979 science fiction horror film Alien. By 2003, the development of
>   Alien vs. Predator took precedence, and the project remained dormant
>   until 2009 when Scott again showed interest. Spaihts wrote a script
>   for a prequel to the events of the Alien films, but Scott opted for a
>   different direction to avoid repeating cues from those films. In late
>   2010, Lindelof joined the project to rewrite Spaihts's script, and he
>   and Scott developed a story that precedes the story of Alien but is
>   not directly connected to that franchise. According to Scott, although
>   the film shares "strands of Alien's DNA, so to speak", and takes place
>   in the same universe, Prometheus explores its own mythology and ideas.

So it's clear that Prometheus is a sequel to first alien film and their may be one more Prometheus film which will fill the gap between First Alien film and Prometheus and AVP's is just like a spinoff.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a movie writer but I must say when watching the Prometheus movie I thought I seen a connection to Predator and Alien as well.

If you remember back to the part were the one crew member was infected and then started to feel sick and started to change and then they torched him out side the ship.

Well if you recall after that when they went to check because they thought he was still alive but by then he had changed completely and looked more humanoid like how the Predator looks.

If you recall his facial features and the beyond normal human strength just wanted to throw that thought out there.

Comment: I think your opinion yields another question completely unrelated to mine. I guess it'd be best if you ask yours separately.