# The character of Weyland in Prometheus and Alien vs. Predator

Tags: character, prometheus, aliens-vs-predator

Is Mr. Weyland a great grandchild of the Weyland in *Alien vs. Predator*?

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/4389/49.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lindelof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damon_Lindelof) explains [About the prometheus and AVP connection in an interview as:-](http://www.craveonline.com/film/interviews/190017-fundamental-mysteries-damon-lindelof-on-prometheus-and-star-trek-2)

> **Q:** You said nothing is an accidental reference, so is there a possible
>   intentional Alien Vs. Predator reference in that the Weylands are
>   always seeking eternal life?
>
> **Lindelof:** You mean in terms of Charles Bishop Weyland? Look, as to what’s canon
>   and what’s not canon, for me as a screenwriter it’s transcended by
>   Ridley as a director. Here’s the thing. Ridley invented this. He
>   created this Alien universe. He birthed it out of his own heart and
>   soul. So he gets to do whatever it is he wants to do and he wanted to
>   use Weyland as a conduit in the story, and was not interested at all
>   when I said to him, “You know, Weyland was a character in one of the
>   Alien Vs. Predator movies,” he just sort of looked at me like I had
>   just slapped him in the face. That was the beginning, middle and end
>   of all Alien Vs. Predator references in our story process.

That clearly indicates that they want to completely ignore **AVP**, and Weyland characters in both movies have no relation.

Answer (score 4):

Prometheus is intended to be the prequel to the Alien directed by Ridley Scott. Alien vs Predator was a spin-off franchise and has nothing to do with Alien or Prometheus time lines.

There is no relation what so ever between weyland characters in both movies.

Comment: Thanks...I sure wish everyone would get their "Stuff" straight then.

Answer (score 0):

Even if not outright stated, Charles Weyland can almost certainly be concluded as being the father of Peter Weyland (who was born in 1990 and rose to power eight years after Charles died), seeing as the history and character of Peter was designed in such a way that you could easily interpret Peter and his iteration of the company as existing in succession to Charles and his iteration of the company, and this seems to be the general agreement over at Fox, especially considering they persistently insist upon including Alien vs. Predator and Prometheus within the same continuity, regardless of Scott's interests or opinions (it's not in fact his property after all). For further details; https://sites.google.com/view/xenoversecenter/xenoblog/2020-archive/on-the-kinship-of-charles-and-peter-weyland