# The movie Prometheus and Alien android designs:

Tags: plot-explanation, aliens, aliens-vs-predator, alien-3

Why are the androids in [ALIENS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliens_%28film%29) and [ALIEN³](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_3) designed after the original Weyland from [AVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVP%3a_Alien_vs._Predator), but not in any of the other movies?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the main point to consider is that the *Alien* (and later *Alien/Predator*) universe **is not an entirely pre-thought and consistently grown universe**, with the stories well tied into each other. There were different producers, directors and story-tellers taking turns on the story and including additional stuff (like the merge with the *Predator*-franchise). And with the resulting advantage of a conglomerate of entirely different genres and styles comes the disadvantage of sacrificing some coherence and overall consistency of the story. Rather than continuing some established universe, future sequels rather took their pick at interpreting and contuing the story, **referencing previous events and characters as they see fit (or not at all)**, neccessarily introducing some problems with previous story aspects in the course. But we might be able to provide a little rundown of how the character of *Weyland* and the androids developed in the movies:

---

The first [*Alien*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078748/) movie **did likely not have any future sequels in mind right from the start**, let alone the appearance of the original creator of the androids and the fact of them being modeled after him. Those androids were just modeled in some varied way (as the crew of the *Nostromo* also didn't know about *Ash* being an android at all). Thus this aspect was just not thought about yet. Then in [*Aliens*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/) the role of the synthetic human was played by *Lance Henriksen*. I think also at this point there was likely not yet a consideration of the androids being modeled after any real life person, but just in a normal diversified way.

Then at the end of [*Alien³*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103644/) we have *Lance Henriksen* play the head of the *Weyland* company. But it seems that was rather introduced into the story as a reminiscence (for both *Ripley* and the audience) to the original *Bishop*, chosen for *Ripley* to better draw a connection to someone she already had a connection to (in the same way as the *T-800* was selected to kill *John Connor* due to his previous relationship with him, to draw a connection to an entirely different movie franchise). It is IMHO not clear if this was really the head of the *Weyland* company (as he stated, I think) or just another of those androids modeled after the original *Weyland* and just claiming to be him (though, IMDb lists him as *"Bishop II"*). But disregarding if the role from *Alien³* was really supposed to be *Weyland* or not, **the fact that the androids were modeled after the original *Weyland* was not introduced, let alone thought about, before the creation of the story for *Alien³*** and the fact that not neccessarily all of the androids were modeled after him (be it in past movies, or also in [*Alien: Resurrection*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118583/)) **was just a minor inconsistency to be accepted**, or rather a coincidence for *Ripley* to stumble across one of the "*Weyland*-style" models.

Then there came the merge of franchises with [*AVP: Aliens vs. Predator*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0370263/). This built upon the previously introduced fact of at least *Bishop* being modeled after *Weyland* and used this to make *Lance Henriksen* reprise the role of the original *Weyland* in the present (our present, when *AVP* is set). But this was IMHO rather made as **a neat reference to the previous movies than to really strengthen the fact of *all* androids being built after *Weyland***.

Then there is also the newest installment of [*Prometheus*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1446714/) which was itself made as a (maybe/maybe not) prequel to the first *Alien* movie and *Ridley Scott* has clarified that **it is [not related to any of the following movies (or at least any of the AVP movies)](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/4389/49) in any way**. So [there isn't any connection of *Prometheus*' *Weyland* to his depictions in the previous movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8658/49), let alone the fact of him modeling his androids after his likeness.

---

So to sum up, the out-of-universe answer is that this aspect wasn't thought out right from the beginning and **this is just one of those little inconsistencies resulting from the heterogenous nature of the *Aliens/Predator* universe**. If you would like to have some *possible* in-universe reason, then it might very well be that **not all of the androids were modeled after *Charles Bishop Weyland* or his descendants**, but only some of them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Lance Henriksen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lance_Henriksen) assumed the role of android in Aliens and did a character as Weyland in AVP. Aliens and Alien vs predator universe are not related by any means.

Comment: He also showed up at the end of Alien III, is he supposed to be the likeness of the Weyland image or is this a coincidence?

Comment: AVP came after alien 3 right? my answer remains the same.

Comment: I don't think Lance's character in AVP was named Weyland, but I could be wrong. Need to watch it again.

Comment: Yes, he is the First version of Mr. Weyland. Charles Bishop, See it at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_vs._Predator_(film)