# AvP and Covenant Timeline conflict?

Tags: continuity, alien-covenant, aliens-vs-predator

In Alien vs Predator it is revealed, that the aliens are an ancient race that for at least hundreds or thousands of years are the greatest prey for the great predators. Alien vs Predator is set in the late end of the millennium.

Now with the new plot from Alien:Covenant, the alien race is merely demystified to just a science project by some synthetic dude, made up of a weaponized genetic mixture.

Is AvP just a setting outside of the canon of the alien universe?
Why is it, that the race has been demystified in any case?

Comment: Related: [How is Prometheus connected to Alien vs. Predator in the chronological sense?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4389/how-is-prometheus-connected-to-alien-vs-predator-in-the-chronological-sense)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### AvP is not canon.

From [here](http://www.alien-covenant.com/news/fox-make-alien-vs-predator-movies-canon):

> the promotional website Weyland Industries retconned the AvP movies from the canon by having Peter Weyland (Guy Pearce, pictured below) as the founder of Weyland Corp, as opposed to having AVP's Charles Bishop Weyland (Lance Henriksen) as the founder of Weyland Industries.

Ridley Scott also [doesn't consider AvP a part of the Alien franchise](http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/alien/feature/a828466/is-alien-vs-predator-canon-alien-covenant/).

> Bringing Scott back to the franchise he launched all those years ago, Fox did not find a cheerleader for Alien vs Predator.
>
> Damon Lindelof – one of Prometheus's writers – tells a story about raising the issue of Charles Bishop Weyland from AvP with the director (via Crave): "He just sort of looked at me like I had just slapped him in the face."

AvP were kinda like Freddy Vs Jason, just a fun what-if, and not really a core part of the story.