# Did the Predator franchise ever address AvP or AvP2 being canon or not?

Tags: production, chronology, predator, aliens-vs-predator, aliens-vs-predator-requiem

*Alien vs. Predator* and *Aliens vs. Predator: Requiem* have been considered non-canon from the point of Alien franchise and has been addressed in this site many times too:

[How is Prometheus connected to Alien vs. Predator in the chronological sense?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/4389/1190)

[AvP and Covenant Timeline conflict?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/75387/1190)

But I want to know, did anyone involved from Predator franchise ever acknowledge it being canon or non-canon, or is it mentioned in any of the sequel?

Answer (score 1):

The first three Predator movies reference Alien or AvP only in a sense that there is the Xenomorph skull in the trophy case in Predator 2.

However, the upcoming movie The Predator (released in September 2018) will reference at least some of the things in the AvP movies. In the trailer, there is a mask worn by one of the young blood Predators in AvP. What is more, The Predator is using a shuriken weapon first seen in AvP. Also, the movie will feature the ceremonial spear that Lex was given at the end of the first movie.

This seems to indicate that the new Predator franchise considers the AvP movies canon.

I personally think at least the first AvP movie is fun and have included both movie events in my [Alien Timeline](https://www.avpcentral.com/alien-timeline).